# Select a css3 element by grandparent's parent's class

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Im implementing multiple rangesliders into my site and because this is code generated in real time I need to select some elements by their parents parent class.

this is the code the timeline class is the last one i can set myself and i need to be able to edit the `.irs-line-right` without changing my other sliders

[image: this is the code the timeline class is the last one i can set myself and i need to be able to edit the .irs-line-right without changing my other sliders]

Comment: Add code instead of screenshot. Also you want to create selector for dynamically adding style using JS/jquery or for adding style using css? 
If css then just adding space hierarchy you can reach to grandchild or its child. (to select 2nd or 3rd child, etc use nth-child pseudo selector) https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you stated that you want to access an element through a parent element. I don't see why this is necessary, but it's surely possible. You can change the element style, attribute, etc. through js. However, it's best to simply use css if you only need to change the style of the span with the class 'irs-line-right'. I'll show how to do this in both css and javascript.

***CSS Example***

In css you can change the style of the 'irs-line-right'
by referencing the 'timeline' div (and no other ids or classes) as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/2t3w0826/

```
.timeline > div:nth-of-type(2) > span > span > span > span:nth-of-type(3)
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

***Javascript Example***

https://jsfiddle.net/8qceLgw8/

```
var array_of_all_timelines = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline");
for(var loop=0; loop < array_of_all_timelines.length; loop++)
{
  var element_irs_line_right = array_of_all_timelines[loop].children[1].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[2];
  element_irs_line_right.style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
```